# highlight navigation PHP

Tags: php, highlighting

I've launched a website a while back and successfully used Javascript + CSS to highlight the current page on the navigation.  However, it is not working in Safari and it does not validate well, when using Javascript, so I decided to have PHP assign the CSS id to the HTML elements.  So far, it works fine, compared to the other times where there was two of each link displayed, when it was attempted in PHP.  My problem is that all links look normal and the CSS property is not applied.  I have a feeling that it has to do with my PHP code, but I'm not certain.

The site address is [here](http://brycec.dyndns.org)

As for the PHP code, here it is:

```
<?php
echo('<li><span class="bold">Main</span>');
echo('<ul>');
if ($page=="home")
{
echo('<li><a id="current" href="index.shtml">Home</a></li>');
}
else
{
echo('<li><a href="index.shtml">Home</a></li>');
}
if ($page=="faq")
{
echo('<li><a id="current" href="faq.shtml">FAQ</a></li>');
}
else
{
echo('<li><a href="faq.shtml">FAQ</a></li>');
}
if ($page=="about")
{
echo('<li><a id="current" href="about.shtml">About Bryce</a></li>');
}
else
{
echo('<li><a href="about.shtml">About Bryce</a></li>');
}
echo('<li><a href="contact.php">Contact Bryce</a></li>');
if ($page=="sign guestbook")
{
echo('<li><a id="current" href="sign.shtml">Sign Guestbook</a></li>');
}
else
{
echo('<li><a href="sign.shtml">Sign Guestbook</a></li>');
}
if ($page=="view guestbook")
{
echo('<li><a id="current" href="view.shtml">View Guestbook</a></li>');
}
else
{
echo('<li><a href="view.shtml">View Guestbook</a></li>');
}
echo('</ul>');
echo('</li>');
echo('<li><span class="bold">Info</span>');
echo('<ul>');
if ($page=="projects")
{
echo('<li><a id="current" href="projects.shtml">Projects</a></li>');
}
else
{
echo('<li><a href="projects.shtml">Projects</a></li>');
}
if ($page=="books")
{
echo('<li><a id="current" href="books.shtml">Books</a></li>');
}
else
{
echo('<li><a href="books.shtml">Books</a></li>');
}
echo('</ul>');
echo('</li>');
echo('<li><span class="bold">Misc.</span>');
echo('<ul>');
if ($page=="cover designs")
{
echo('<li><a id="current" href="coverdesigns.shtml">Cover Designs</a></li>');
}
else
{
echo('<li><a href="coverdesigns.shtml">Cover Designs</a></li>');
}
echo('<li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.lulu.com/brycecampbellsbooks">Lulu Store</a></li>');
echo('<li><a href="rss/">RSS</a></li>');
echo('</ul>');
echo('</li>');

?>
```

In order to give you guys an idea of what the highlighting effect should look like, here is the CSS that is supposed to be applied to the current page:

```
#current {
   font-style: italic;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000000;
  }
```

When looking up what I was doing wrong, it told me that I was implementing it right, but it does not seem that the PHP is getting the values.

Comment: Can you show us how $page is being set?

Comment: Ouch.  I recommend you move to using a php templating system to make sure that you separate your display from your presentation logic.

Comment: @Tchalvak PHP **is** a templating system. That's just spaghetti mess.

Comment: I'm using SSI to deal with content that is most likely to change.  I'd rather use PHP for things like importing RSS and a redirect, as well as the guestbook.  True PHP based layouts could help a lot, it would just take a whole lot longer, considering how much code there is.  Doing it this way takes less time, even though it is harder.

Comment: @Timothy PHP is indeed a templating system, and once a programmer is familiar with what's involved with separating content from presentation, it's fine to implement that separation yourself without a templating system inbetween.  But until a php programmer has a clear idea of the benefits and process of good separation of content, I recommend using a separate third-party templating system to get a handle on the best practices.

Comment: @Tchalvak - Why have someone learn a templating language when they are already trying to learn php (which is a template language)?

Comment: Because it ends up being simpler in the long run.  Debugging mixed html/css/javascript/php while learning all of them in a clump will be much much harder than learning php and writing the php with the html well separated by templates, + learning html and writing html in templates, + learning css and writing the css in external stylesheets, + learning javascript and writing the javascript in external java scripts.  Besides, the more well separated all those are, the easier it is to follow the ideal of progressive enhancement: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement

Answer (score 4):

for the love of god don't use that code!!!! do this!

```
<li><a href=""<?php if($page=='about'): ?> id="current"<?php endif; ?>>about</a></li>
<li><a href=""<?php if($page=='otherpage'): ?> id="current"<?php endif; ?>>other page</a></li>
```

youre giving the php haters more ammo!

Comment: It's much simpler to read the way I did, but I can somewhat see what's going on in that one, since I seen it before in a C programming class.

Comment: I tried your method and it did not work.  The navigation displays 'id=current' before every link.  maybe a different variation will, otherwise my method was pretty close.

Comment: it does work. your $page variable is probably wrong. update your questions and tell us how youre getting the $page variable.

Comment: I also use short tags for views, the code is even cleaner. Of course you need to make sure they are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo $page;
```

to see what you get. Could you post the code that assigns `$page`?

Comment: It should be in the source code, which can be access from the page the URL is given, since it is placed before everything in the HTML file.  I was thinking of attempting that though.

Comment: Okay it did not display anything.

Comment: Although it is visible at the URL, each of the pages in the navigation has this at the very top

<?php $page="<pagename>" ?>

Comment: Does the php file end in .php? It looks like php is not parsing your files, so the php code within isn't working.

Comment: the PHP to assign data to the $page variable is inside the HTML file, as there is no common name between the pages, while the PHP to do the highlighting is in its own file.  Using PHP_SELF might not be of any help in a separate file from the HTML either.

Comment: All files containing php need to end in .php so that the php server can parse the code. If they don't, the php code will just be passed to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

After programming in php for years, and learning what not to do by long periods of trial and error, here are some overall recommendations for making your debugging and your life easier in general, based on that code:

- Make a very clear separation between your php and your html.  In other words, have the html of your app in templates.  At a bare minimum those templates could be php files that you include that have the minimum actual php necessary.  Beyond the bare minimum, it will probably be easier for you if you use a third-party templating system.  I recommend smarty.  It's totally possible to keep everything well separated by good discipline, but it's much *easier* to keep things separate using a good templating system, in the beginning.
- In general in php we have the luxury of knowing generally what a page should look by the time we have pulled the input from $_REQUEST and the data from the datastore/database and done our operations on them.  So once we have all the data exactly how we want it, we should be able to have a whole section that involves manipulating input data and then just pass everything to a template with some minimal display logic in it to show the look of the final page.  E.g. instead of

  `if($page == 'about'){ echo "<a href='about.php'>About</a>"; }`

  determine the type of data outside of the html and only *then* pass on that determination on, e.g.

  `$possible_links = array('about'=>array('href'='about.php', 'text'=>'About'), 'other'=>array('href'=>'other.php', 'text'='other pages'));
  $current_link = $possible_links[$current];
  ...
  ...
  in separate script, optimally:
  ...
  echo "<a href='".$current_link['href']."`>".$current_link['text']."";

`

- In your own code, try looking into frameworks using the MVC pattern, for a very robust separation technique.  Obviously if you're working on someone else's legacy code, that's not as easy, so in that case just try to keep things compartmentalized as much as you can (especially html from php).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an easier way to do what you want:

```
<?php
// heredoc syntax ftw!
$menu = <<<MENU
<ul id="nav">
 <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="/foo">Foo</a></li>
 <li><a href="/bar">Bar</a></li>
 <li><a href="/baz">Baz</a></li>
 <li><a href="/inga">Inga</a></li>
</ul>
MENU;
$lines = split("\n", $menu);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
 $current = false;
 preg_match('/href="([^"]+)"/', $line, $url);
 if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 5) === substr($url[1], 0, 5)) {
  $line = str_replace('<li><a h', '<li class="current"><a h', $line);
 }
 echo $line."\n";
}
?>
```

Just edit `$menu` at the top and the script will take care of the rest.

Answer (score -2):

I dont find any problem in your php code. better can you change your css like below...

```
.current {
   font-style: italic;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000000;
  }
```

Comment: No; Kira is targeting the element by `id` attribute, not by `class`. Targeting by `id` attribute is done with an octothorpe, while targeting by `class` is done with a period.

Comment: I'm calling an id though, not a class.